# Find inverse of modified Fourier Transform and Fourier Series

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Given that $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, find $F(\omega)$ such that,
$$
f(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F(\omega)cos(\omega \hspace{1mm}log(t)) d\omega
$$

Also please find $f_k$ such that,

$$
f(t) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} f_k \hspace{1mm}cos(k \hspace{1mm} log(t))
$$

The first thing I noticed is that this is a very similar problem to finding the Taylor Series coefficients of $f(t)$ with complex powers of $t$.

$$
f(t) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} f_k \hspace{1mm} Re\{e^{k \hspace{1mm} log(t) i}\} 
= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} f_k \hspace{1mm} Re\{t^{ki}\} 
= Re\{ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} f_k \hspace{1mm} t^{ki}\} 
$$

This led me to try the same trick of taking the derivative of this expression. However, since this is a polynomial with complex powers, taking the regular derivative is not helpful. Since,

$$
\frac{d}{dt} t^{ki} = t^{ki-1}
$$

Maybe try taking an imaginary order derivative https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differintegral#Definitions_via_transforms ?

New Approach:

Define a new function $g(t) = f(t^{-i})$.

$$
g(t) = f(t^{-i}) = Re\{ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} f_k \hspace{1mm} (t^{-i})^{ki}\} 
= Re\{ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} f_k \hspace{1mm} t^{-i^2 k}\} 
= Re\{ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} f_k \hspace{1mm} t^k\} 
= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} Re \{ f_k \} \hspace{1mm} t^k
$$

Now the coefficients we are searching for are the coefficients of $g(t)$.

$$
Re \{ f_k \} = \frac{1}{k!} \big[\frac{d^k}{dt^k} g(t)\big]_{t=0}
$$

$$
\therefore Re \{ f_k \} = \frac{1}{k!} \big[\frac{d^k}{dt^k} f(t^{-i})\big]_{t=0}
$$

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck? Without including these things your question it will get closed.

Comment: I have added some steps that I have taken